Creating effect plots of results from ordinal regression (with interactions)
I've had a paper accepted in a journal and the reviewer has asked me to create effect plots out of a model of ordinal regression (with interactions), which I've never done before. I cannot get it to work so I figured it would be reasonable to ask here.
Any suggestions? Or if someone could point me in the right direction?
Here's the piece of code I run for my ordinal regression and the output it generates:
library(ordinal)
library(rcompanion) 
library(MASS) 
library(brant) 
library(AER)
library(car)

options(scipen = 999)

Ordinaldf <- read.delim(file.choose()) 
View(Ordinaldf)

Ordinaldf$AoA_scaled <- c(scale(Ordinaldf$AoA))
Ordinaldf$Ra_scaled <- c(scale(Ordinaldf$Range))
Ordinaldf$Fr_scaled <- c(scale(Ordinaldf$Frequency))
Ordinaldf$Div_scaled <- c(scale(Ordinaldf$Diversity))

Ordinaldf$Grade<-as.factor(Ordinaldf$Grade) 
Ordinaldf$Text<-as.factor(Ordinaldf$Text)

modelnull <- clm(as.factor(Grade) ~ 1,
                 data = Ordinaldf,
                 link = "logit")

model1 <- clm(Grade ~ Text *(AoA_scaled + Ra_scaled + Fr_scaled + Div_scaled),
              data = Ordinaldf,
              link = "logit")

anova(modelnull, model1)
nagelkerke(fit = model1, null = modelnull)  
summary(model1)
confint(model1)
exp(coef(model1))
exp(confint(model1))

model1 <- clm(Grade ~ Text + AoA_scaled + Ra_scaled + Fr_scaled + Div_scaled + 
                Text*AoA_scaled + Text*Ra_scaled + Text*Fr_scaled + Text*Div_scaled, 
              data = Ordinaldf,
              link = "logit")


  link  threshold nobs logLik  AIC    niter max.grad cond.H 
     logit flexible  165  -261.80 551.60 5(0)  1.51e-12 6.9e+01

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)
TextTeacher            -0.008491   0.284899  -0.030    0.9762
AoA_scaled             -1.374471   0.311885  -4.407 0.0000105
Ra_scaled              -0.039952   0.318091  -0.126    0.9000
Fr_scaled              -0.056617   0.307116  -0.184    0.8537
Div_scaled             -0.367834   0.259090  -1.420    0.1557
TextTeacher:AoA_scaled  0.772882   0.375991   2.056    0.0398
TextTeacher:Ra_scaled  -0.065245   0.428996  -0.152    0.8791
TextTeacher:Fr_scaled  -0.116927   0.418322  -0.280    0.7799
TextTeacher:Div_scaled -0.343463   0.356337  -0.964    0.3351
                      
TextTeacher               
AoA_scaled             ***
Ra_scaled                 
Fr_scaled                 
Div_scaled                
TextTeacher:AoA_scaled *  
TextTeacher:Ra_scaled     
TextTeacher:Fr_scaled     
TextTeacher:Div_scaled    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
A|B -2.12352    0.29146  -7.286
B|C -1.09145    0.24938  -4.377
C|D -0.05468    0.23512  -0.233
D|E  0.89250    0.24752   3.606
E|F  2.36155    0.30808   7.665



One simple way is to use my ggeffects-package, which lets you easily visualize results for more complex models or model specifications.
Unlike the raw coefficients from the summary(), which are difficult to interpret (because you have logit-links and interactions), it is indeed often much easier to create such effects plots as shown below.
As additional steps, you could even calculate pairwise comparisons and test whether differences between predictions are statistically significant or not.
The workflow using the ggeffects package is really simple and basically the same for different types of regression models or different model specifications, so you don't need to learn a new "syntax" each time. See as a short example this vignette.
library(ggeffects)
data(wine, package = "ordinal")
m1 <- ordinal::clm(rating ~ temp * contact, data = wine)
predict_response(m1, c("temp", "contact")) |> plot()


Created on 2024-06-27 with reprex v2.1.0

The answer by @Daniel may be the most "statistically relevant" way to present the results.
But depending on your audience --- and how many variables and levels you need to present ---, you might consider some simpler-to-interpret plots.
One idea is to use the emmeans package, and present the emmeans and confidence intervals from cld(), perhaps in an interaction plot (e.g. rcompanion.org/handbook/images/image019.png).  The problem is that the y-axis isn't easily interpretable for ordinal regression this way.
Another idea is to do something similar, but present something easier to understand. Maybe medians and confidence intervals for the medians.  Or maybe just medians. Or maybe medians and IQR.  These don't really "match" the ordinal regression analysis, but might be good for a visualization.
